# Can I make this "requires" compatible?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, coinbase-api

I've been doing CS50 and now I'm in my final project. I need this library called cbpro to finish my project and I keep get this errors. This cbpro helps me to connect to Coinbase API and work in my final project that is an app to get some account details. How do I fix it? I tried `pip install uplink` but it did not work.

Repo: https://github.com/danpaquin/coinbasepro-python

```
finalproject/ $ pip install cbpro
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting cbpro
  Downloading cbpro-1.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Collecting six==1.10.0
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: websocket-client==0.40.0 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cbpro) (0.40.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pymongo==3.5.1 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cbpro) (3.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sortedcontainers>=1.5.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cbpro) (2.4.0)
Collecting requests==2.13.0
  Downloading requests-2.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (584 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 584.6/584.6 kB 167.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: six, requests, cbpro
  Attempting uninstall: six
    Found existing installation: six 1.16.0
    Uninstalling six-1.16.0:
      Successfully uninstalled six-1.16.0
  Attempting uninstall: requests
    Found existing installation: requests 2.28.0
    Uninstalling requests-2.28.0:
      Successfully uninstalled requests-2.28.0
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
uplink 0.9.7 requires requests>=2.18.0, but you have requests 2.13.0 which is incompatible.
uplink 0.9.7 requires six>=1.13.0, but you have six 1.10.0 which is incompatible.
submit50 3.1.1 requires requests>=2.19, but you have requests 2.13.0 which is incompatible.
jsbeautifier 1.14.3 requires six>=1.13.0, but you have six 1.10.0 which is incompatible.
check50 3.3.6 requires requests>=2.19, but you have requests 2.13.0 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed cbpro-1.1.4 requests-2.13.0 six-1.10.0
finalproject/ $
```

Then when I `flask run`:

```
finalproject/ $ flask run
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cs50/lib/flask", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(flask.cli.main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 988, in main
    cli.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 579, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
finalproject/ $     return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 850, in run_command
    app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 299, in __init__
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 333, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 393, in load_app
    app = locate_app(import_name, None, raise_if_not_found=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 234, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/workspaces/8481664/finalproject/app.py", line 8, in <module>
    from helpers import login_required, lookup, usd, check, on_message, on_error, on_close, on_open
  File "/workspaces/8481664/finalproject/helpers.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .cookies import RequestsCookieJar, cookiejar_from_dict
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 174, in <module>
    class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```